# I've remembered to be faithful

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Do the first pair of sentences mean the same? Here, remember means to keep in mind.

> 1. I've remembered to be faithful to my wife.

> 2. I've been remembering to be faithful to my wife.

Do the second pair of sentences have the same meaning? Here, remember means to recall knowledge from memory.

> 3. I've remembered many times my lost dog over the past month.

> 4. I've been remembering my lost dog over the past month.

Comment: 1 & 2 are grammatical, and mean what you think they mean, but are rather unnatural. I am sure my wife would be happier if I never even thought about being unfaithful, rather than having to 'remember' to be faithful. Likewise, my employer might be worried if I said I have remembered not to steal money from him. If you say you 'remember' not to do a bad thing you are implying that you might possibly do that thing.

Comment: 3 and 4 are not very idiomatic. You could say "When I saw the greyhound in the park, I remembered my own lost dog", but for repeated occasions we would usually use _thought of_ instead.

Comment: @KateBunting - would [Christina Rossetti](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45000/remember-56d224509b7ae) have agreed?

Comment: Asking if text is correct or can be improved is off -topic

Answer (score 1):

If someone 'remembers to do something', they keep it in mind, because they might forget otherwise. I remembered to buy some bread and milk on the way home from work. I try to remember to take the key out of my car dashboard when I park. If a husband says that he 'remembered' to be faithful to his wife, that means that it is possible that he might forget, and absent-mindedly have sex with someone else. This might be an odd thing for a husband to admit to.

> remember to do sth   A2
>
> to not forget to do something:
>
> *Did you remember to do the shopping?*

[Remember (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remember)